# polynomial of degree 3 over set of rationals having only two rational zeros.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Does there exist a polynomial of degree 3 over the set of rationals which has only two rational zeros?

Comment: Suppose there does.  What happens when you construct it from its zeroes?

Comment: Yes, if you count roots geometrically. You can have a cubic polynomial with only two rational numbers as roots. e.g. $(x-1)x^2$. No, if count roots algebraically.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. Lets assume it has exactly two rational zeros and one irrational zero. Then sum of zeros = irrational but from the sum of zeros formula we get it's equal to $-b/a$ which is rational. Hence contradiction

Comment: @achille hui's point is valid.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I got your point. Thanks for reply. I am new in this forum, so forgive if any mistake.

Comment: I think you mean $-b/a$